# FFMPEG: Using Zoompan drawtext jiggle issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I have applied the Zoompan effect (only Zoom Out) and Fad In and Fad Out effect to drawtext using FFmpeg but its output is text is Zoom out with jiggle (shaking right and left).
How i solve this issue?
Here is Command:

```
ffmpeg -i D:/video/square_630_630_42.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:320x320,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,setsar=1,drawtext=textfile="D\\:/video/temp.txt":fontsize=20:fontfile=Consolas.ttf:fontcolor=ff00ff:box=1:boxborderw=1:boxcolor=00000000:shadowcolor=000000:shadowx=1:shadowy=1.5:alpha='if(lt(t,4),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-4)/1,if(lte(t,(10-3)),1,if(lt(t,10),(10-t)/1,0))))':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,zoompan=z='if(gt(in,(3*25)),if(lt(in,((3+5)*25)),1.5-((in-(3*25))*0.004)))':s=420x420:d=0:x=iw/2-(iw/zoom/2):y=ih/2-(ih/zoom/2):fps=25[txta];[0][txta] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:shortest=1:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2+210[v1];[v1]format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast finale_Zoom_Text.mp4
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [ffmpeg: smooth zoompan with no jiggle](https://superuser.com/questions/1112617/ffmpeg-smooth-zoompan-with-no-jiggle).

Comment: @llogan it's working on Image perfectly but when i will apply on the text that is reproduced jiggle effect.

Comment: i have used : drawtext=text='Text':fontfile=Consolas.ttf:fontcolor=ff00ff:box=1:boxborderw=1:boxcolor=00000000:shadowcolor=0x000000:shadowx=1.5:shadowy=1.5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2-ascent:fontsize=(50-(t+2)) for zoom out effect but its display like static zoom out slow i want Zoom smooth like image zoom out usinf zoomout. if any one help me ?